# Zoom in/out doesn't work on my mobile phone (Blogger)

Tags: html, blogger

I try to add the text below on my head-tag, but the zoom in/out is not working on my mobile phone.

```
<meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1' name='viewport'/>
```

ex: http://chenweilun.blogspot.tw/2016/11/test.html

It works, but when I add the following text in my article:

```
<meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1' name='viewport'/>
```

ex: http://chenweilun.blogspot.tw/2016/07/blog-post.html

It stops working. Did I miss something?

There is some reference link about the zoom in/out on blogger: http://fuseinteractive.ca/blog/avoiding-landscape-zoom-in-effect-on-mobile#.WCgKs_B97IU

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Blogger template they set the scale by this meta tag

```
<meta expr:content='data:blog.isMobile?quot;width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0,minimum-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1.0&quot;:&quot;width=1100&quot;' name='viewport'/>
```

Replace the above with the next meta tag after your `<head>` element directly to allow user-scalable. you can also change the maximum-scale value.

```
<meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=10.0, user-scalable=yes' name='viewport'/>
```

Comment: In most cases, blogger mobile templates don't accept customization. my advice is to make your template responsive and show desktop template on mobile devices. This is also good for SEO.

Comment: I tried it. It seems to be a good idea. Is it possible to make the desktop template looked like the mobile template on mobile devices? I hope I could move the right area to bottom area. And the width for my site fit my device width when I open my site.

Comment: Yes, you need to make your template responsive with different devices, please read this [article](http://www.bloggingspell.com/make-blogger-mobile-friendly/) carefully.

Answer (score 1):

first of all

1. sign in your [blogger](https://www.onlinestudy.xyz/?m=0).
2. and go to the Theme Section.
3. next edit HTML.
4. search " Viewport ".
5. and you got something like :

```html
<meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1' name='viewport'/>
```

6. And Replace with :

```html
<meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=10.0, user-scalable=yes' name='viewport'/>
```

thank you :)